# PHP While cicle keep loading and give error

Tags: php, while-loop

guys i have the following code, but when i execute it on my site, the site give me internal server error 500

```
$Data = $con->prepare("SELECT Example1,Example2,Example3,Example4 FROM SITES WHERE Email=:Email");
$Data->execute(array(
    ':Email' => $Email,
));
if ($Data->rowCount() > 0) {
    $Rows = $Data->rowCount();
    $CL = 1;
    $Result = $Data->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    while ($CL <= $Rows) {
        $Example1 = $Result['Example1'];
        $Example2 = $Result['Example2'];
        $Example3 = $Result['Example3'];
        $Example4 = $Result['Example4'];
        $CL = $CL++;
        echo
        '<tr class="tr">
                        <td class="td"><?=$Example1?></td> 
                        <td class="td"><?=$Example2?></td> 
                        <td class="td"><?=$Example3?></td> 
                        <td class="td"><?=$Example4?></td> 
                        <td class="td"></td>  
                    </tr>';
    }
}
```

I want that for every row where `email=:email` php will print an html row of an existing table.Thanks in advice, have a good day!

Comment: look in your logs. what error are you getting? at what line?

Comment: `$CL=$CL++;`  is wrong. it should be just `$CL++;` Because `$CL++` returns the **old** value of the variable. So that line increment `$CL` and then immediatly undo that incrementation. http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php

Comment: put "or die (pg_last_error($con));" at the end of your prepare and exec

Comment: A 500 error is a very generic error message that covers almost anything that can go wrong in a PHP script. You'll want to look at your server error logs to find out *why* it's throwing a 500 error.

Comment: Also, probably a mistype, but you're comparing CR and incrementing CL

Comment: Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at ... to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

Comment: Also, you're using shortcodes inside a single-quoted string. It won't do what you want. This won't throw a 500 error, but it also isn't correct at all.

Comment: So i have double quote the echo "..." like this ?

Comment: Yes, and no. You can use the double quotes, but get rid of the short codes `<?=  ?>`. You only need those when you're not inside a PHP block, and only if short codes are turned on. Using a double-quoted string tells the PHP processor to process any variables inside that string.

Answer (score 0):

#### Try this {Let's us know if it works for you}

```
$Data = $con->prepare("SELECT Example1,Example2,Example3,Example4 FROM SITES WHERE Email=:Email");
$Data->execute(array(
    ':Email' => $Email,
));
if ($Data->rowCount() > 0) {
    $Rows = $Data->rowCount();
    $CL = 1;
    $Result = $Data->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    while ($CL <= $Rows) {
        $Example1 = $Result['Example1'];
        $Example2 = $Result['Example2'];
        $Example3 = $Result['Example3'];
        $Example4 = $Result['Example4'];
        //$CL = $CL++; This is bad;
        $CL++;
        echo
        '<tr class="tr">'; <?
                        <td class="td"><?php echo $Example1 ;?></td> 
                        <td class="td"><?php echo $Example2 ;?></td> 
                        <td class="td"><?php echo $Example3 ;?></td> 
                        <td class="td"><?php echo $Example4 ;?></td> 
                        <td class="td"></td>  
       <?php
         echo      '</tr>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `td`s will throw errors since it's still in the PHP block. Though changing that code would not fix whatever 500 error the OP is getting.. but we also don't know what the exact error is.

Comment: Nice catch @aynber fixed it :)

Comment: @LasVegasCoder Don't work, but thank you for your help :), but why on the end of the code there is a <?php, atleast the page don't loop, but don't print nothing.